# Android http post gives forbidden error

Tags: php

I am posting some data from android to PHP server using Httppost. Everything was working fine so far. But now I am getting "403 Forbidden" error.

I noticed that If I pass `Cheese Burger X 1 = 4.95}:Sub Total = £4.95` into the `NameValuePair` then it works as expected, but when I pass `Chips X 1 = 0.60}:Sub Total = £0.60` then It gives error 403. I have tried with various combinations and I am sure that it is failing when I change the text else it works.

Any idea what is going on there?

```
31.107.94.39 - - [04/Dec/2012:11:03:58 -0600] "POST /index.php/orders/create HTTP/1.1" 200 13 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

and says this when it fails -

```
 [04/Dec/2012:11:02:48 -0600] "POST /index.php/orders/create HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

Comment: Check the php logs. Android is not producing the 403, the web application is.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I checked the logs and I have updated the questions. See if you can make out anything

Comment: The logs would not record a 404 where your app states a 403. This is not the correct log line. Also, Java 1.4 that is technology developed by the Ancients. Check your Naquada supplies.

Comment: Yeah, 404 was misleading. It is giving 404 because there is no error page. I agree about the Java 1.4. I need to call my shared hosting provider. This is driving me crazy that it works for a specific text and then it fails for other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Problem. The "=" character was causing "`Detected an illegal character in input string`" error. I removed it and that fixed it.